# Fastlane match doesn't use existing signing certificates

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match

So I'm currently setting up a new project and I've realized when creating adhoc and appstore builds. Fastlane doesn't seem to be using the existing certificate which created a couple months back. Instead, it seems to be generating a new certificate and using this to sign my profiles is there a way to specify/force Fastlane to use the old certificate rather than the new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but not simply, since this is not supported by fastlane match. You have two options:

First, you could just use the `get_certificates` (previously *cert*) and `get_provisioning_profile` (previously *sigh*) actions instead of *match* (now called `sync_code_signing`). This gives you everything except the Git repo syncing.

If you want the Git repo syncing (you probably do), then you can manually construct a repo identical to one match would create, but using your existing certs (see [Manually Manage the fastlane match Repo](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#manually-manage-the-fastlane-match-repo)). The basic trick is to create a new repo in precisely the correct structure by following the match source code, and then use `Match::GitHelper.commit_changes` to encrypt it. It's a pain to set up but from there you should be able to sync seamlessly.

Alternatively, you can use `sync_code_signing nuke` to destroy your existing certs and regenerate from scratch. This will get match working at the expense of other teams who may be relying on your old certs.

Comment: starting from fastlane-206.0 Match::GitHelper didn't work

Comment: Its Oct2019 and this is still a pain! :(

Answer (score 0):

you can download your certificate from AppStore and push it to the repository where match stores certificates. It will not create new certificate